# Efficient way to generate a string from a specifc variable in a list of object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a data structure which contains a 'name' variable. (simplified for brevity here)

I end up with a list of these objects at various points in my code.

Is there an easy way to create a comma-separated string containing all the self.name's from this list of objects?

Example:

```
class myobj(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

mylist = [ myobj("foo"), myobj("bar") ]

# I know this is invalid but looking for something along these lines
print "Names=%s" % ",".join(for o in mylist: print o.name)
```

Is there a handy, "inline" way of doing this w/o using extra lines of code and temporary variables?

Comment: `','.join(o.name for o in mylist)`

Comment: Ahh that was it, I knew I seem something like that somewhere. Much thx!

Comment: You could also define a `__str__` or `__unicode__` method on your objects (if you're in control of the class definition) so you wouldn't have to continually select the name when printing, if you're doing it several times.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> class myobj(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...         
>>> mylist = [myobj("foo"), myobj("bar")]
>>> ','.join([obj.name for obj in mylist])
'foo,bar'
```

*Note:*  List comprehensions are more efficient than generator expressions here, because `str.join` implementation will exhaust the generator into a list anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you define function `__str__` for your class, e.g.

```
class myobj(object):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

then you can simply:

```
','.join(map(str, mylist))
```